# Is there a way to add custom attributes to custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

While messing around with custom elements I wondered if one could use custom attributes within the elements (and possibly within their children too). I know VueJS does something similar with attributes like v-bind, v-for, etc; and I know there's probably a lot more going on under the hood there than I realize. I've tried registering custom elements and attempting to retrieve them like so:

```
<new-element cool="Awesome!"> </new-element>

class NewElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.coolAttr = this.getAttribute("cool");
    }
}

customElements.define("new-element", NewElement);
```

However, when loading the page (in Google Chrome for me) the "custom" attributes disappear, and any attempt at getting them retrieves null. Is there a way to "register" these custom attributes, or do I have to stick with data- attributes?

Comment: You don't need to _register_ custom attributes. Your code works (but you are missing to call super() in the constructor)

Comment: I understand that it's not needed, but I would like know if there is a way to do so. And, I'll go ahead and edit that super call in ;)

Comment: Attributes become available in the connectedCallback,  they are not available yet in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Attributes become available in the `connectedCallback`,
  they are **not available** yet in the `constructor`
  *Unless the Custom Element is **PARSED (in the DOM) BEFORE the Element is defined!!***
- Also be aware the `attributeChangedCallback` runs **before** the `connectedCallback`
  *for **Observed attributes***
- Also see: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

```css
.as-console-row-code {
    font: 12px Arial!important;
    background:yellow;
    color:darkred;
}
.as-console-row:after{ display:none!important }
```

```html
<before-element cool="Awesome?">FOO</before-element>

<script>
  class NewElement extends HTMLElement {
    log( ...args ){
      console.log(this.nodeName, `cool:${this.getAttribute("cool")}`,"\t\t\t",...args );
    }
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["cool"];
    }
    constructor() {
      const name = "constructor"; // CAN! run code BEFORE super()!
      // super() sets AND returns the 'this' scope
      super().log(name);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.log("connectedCallback", this.innerHTML || "innerHTML not parsed yet");
      // be aware this.innerHTML is only available for PARSED elements
      // use setTimeout(()=>{...},0) if you do need this.innerHTML
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      this.log(`attributeChangedCallback name:${name}, old:${oldValue}, new:${newValue}`);
    }
  }
  customElements.define("before-element", class extends NewElement {});
  customElements.define("after-element",  class extends NewElement {});
</script>

<after-element cool="Awesome!!">BAR</after-element>
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be easily solved by adding the name of the attributes after "data-".

```html
<New-element data-*="Anything you want" />
```

for example, you can have:

```html
<element data-cool="value">
```

You can have as many custom attributes as you want.

Comment: That's a standard dataset attribute, not a custom attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand one can use data attributes. I was actually wondering if there was a way to actually define an attribute without the need for data attributes.

Comment: He openly stated that he did not want to use datasets.